# Fetching data from MYSQL using Autocomplete no result found

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want a searching like the one in Google. When you start typing there will be suggestions listed in a dropdown so I used autocomplete. My problem is when i type any key the output is "No result found" even though the data that I'm typing is in my database. I check my database connection and its right. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
   <input type="text" name="clientname" id="clientname" />
```

**php** 
This part is editted, i tried the suggestion of @asik but still not working

filename:getautocomplete.php

```
   if (isset($_REQUEST['term'])){
$return_arr = array();

    $stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT * FROM client WHERE CLIENTNAME LIKE :term');
    $stmt->execute(array('term' => '%'.$_GET['term'].'%'));
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($stmt)) {
        $return_arr[] =  $row['CLIENTNAME'];            
    }
    echo json_encode($return_arr);
        }
        else
        {
     echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

**JavaScript**

```
    $(function() {
      $("#clientname" ).autocomplete({
      source: "getautocomplete.php"
   });
  });
```

thanks in advance

Comment: I think, you are using jquery autocomplete. By default, the value posted in as param "term". so you can change $_REQUEST['clientname'] to $_REQUEST['term']

Comment: I change all the clientname to term then mysql_* to mysqli. But still not working.Should I put something before the if statement?thanks

Comment: check whats it sending `getautocomplete.php` using `Firebug` or `Chrome Deve Tool`

Answer (score 0):

try this, you are missing `:` in named param

```
$stmt = $con->prepare('SELECT CLIENTNAME FROM client WHERE CLIENTNAME LIKE :term');
$stmt->execute(array(':term' => '%'.$_REQUEST['term'].'%'));
```

Hope this works, if not you can try formatting the response as `label` & `value`

```
$return_arr[] =  array('label' => $row['CLIENTNAME'], value => $row['CLIENTNAME']);
```

still not working post screenshot of `getautocomplete.php` response using `Firebug`